# Filter an array which is inside an object by clicking on a button using React js

Tags: reactjs

I have an API. When I click on a button, I want to filter the hashtag data which are arrays and those arrays are in their
objects. This is what I did. It doesn't return anything in this code. I need any help you can do.

**This is my code :**

```
const hashtagsHandler = (event, title) => {
  const eventData = event.target.innerText;
  console.log(eventData);
  const filter = bookData.filter((items) => {
    items.hashtags.map((item) => item === eventData);
  });
  console.log(filter);
  if (filter.length !== 0) {
    setHashtag(filter);
    setAllFilter((prevState) => [...prevState], hashtag);
  }
};
```

**My API is something like this:**

```
"data": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "name",
  "typename": "book",
  "hashtags": [
    "a",
    "b",
  ],
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `filter` function doesn't work because it doesn't return anything, the function should return a Boolean value so it can know what to filter out and what to keep. Like this:

```
function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}

const filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter((value) => {
  return value >= 10;
});
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter.

To correct your code you can do it this way:

```
const filter = bookData.filter((item) => item.hashtags.includes('a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filteredData = bookData.filter(
  (items) => items.hashtags.filter((item) => item === eventData).length !== 0
);
console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

It' s simply a syntax problem of array function that returns new array from original array, like filter, map, ...

Full syntax (with curly bracket): `arr.arrFunc((param1, param2) => {/* your logic with return statement */})`.
Use when you need to perform complex modification with if or for statement

Short hand (without curly bracket): `arr.arrFunc((param1, param2) => /* <your logic> */`. Use when performing inline modification

Example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbk1m8oz/)